# I want to read spring properties file that has a map of maps

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, config, properties-file

I want to have a property like below that is a map of maps

```
propertymap = {
    key1:'{subkey1:'subvalue1',subkey2:'subvalue2'}',
    key2:'{subkey3:'subvalue3',subkey4:'subvalue4'}' }

@Value("#{${propertymap}}")  
private Map<String,Map<String,String>> propertymap;
```

used code like above in my config class but got error. please let me know if there is a way to do this.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 17): Unexpected token. Expected 'rcurly(})' but was 'identifier'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the way, I had to just remove the ' after the key

```
propertymap = {  
   key1:{  
      subkey1:'subvalue1',
      subkey2:'subvalue2'
   },
   key2:{  
      subkey3:'subvalue3',
      subkey4:'subvalue4'
   }
}
```

and below code picks it up

```
@Value("#{${propertymap}}")  
private Map<String,Map<String,String>> propertymap;
```

Comment: There hat to be backslashes in the property file - the propertymap has to be one big string on multiple lines e.g. key1:{\ etc.