# @Value injection a map of maps using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, properties

We have a java application that uses Spring (5.0.8) for dependency injection but not managed by Spring Boot. Simple `@Value` injection is achieved by having this in our Java config class

```
final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    StandardEnvironment myEnv = new StandardEnvironment();
    try {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
        propertySources.addFirst( new SystemEnvironmentPropertySource(StandardEnvironment.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME,
                                myEnv.getSystemProperties()));
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setPropertySources(propertySources);
}catch.....
```

the ApplicationContext is started by

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext APPLICATION_CONTEXT =
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class)
```

Then I can just start using the properties as

```
@Component
public class MyService {
    @Value( "${"myvalInSystemProperty"}")
    private String myval;

    ........
}
```

now I want to add a `@Value` injection using SpEL like

```
@Component
public class MyService {

    @Value("#{${usermap}}")
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> usermap;

    ........
}
```

the corresponding properties file is

```
usermap = {
    key1:{  
      subkey1:'subvalue1',
      subkey2:'subvalue2'
   },
    key2:{  
      subkey3:'subvalue3',
      subkey4:'subvalue4'
   }
}
```

I have added the properties file into propertySources like

```
propertySources.addLast( new ResourcePropertySource( "classpath:myMap.properties"));
```

and I got errors like

```
Expression [#{{}] @0: No ending suffix '}' for expression starting at character 0: #{{}
```

for not recognizing my `@Value` injection

Can anyone please shed some light onto this?

Comment: i am trying to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272477/i-want-to-read-spring-properties-file-that-has-a-map-of-maps   but it simply does not work for me.

Comment: Have you tried just `@Value("${usermap}")`?

Comment: TBH @Value is discouraged, you should be using Type-safe Configuration Properties. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Answer (score -1):

i have found the problem. Silly. Needs back slash at the end of line